# Whats going on with my transimpedance amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback, photodiode, transimpedance

Pulling my hair out with this design. I have the following design which was done using analog devices Photodiode Circuit Wizard tool so it should work. The current source in the schemeatic is the photodiode UV-035EQ. the op amps are powered by +-5V.

This setup is for more measuring low level UV light. But as soon as I place the photodiode into darkness I get a horrible waveform with a peak/trough of about +-2V
https://drive.google.com/open?id=18lMKfpOSzvvhQ3yqGymRFszVO9QUYHl7

[image]

Lookig at the photodiode it looks like its working fine I've tried multiple ones and they all seem the same.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3VbZd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What frequency is that? It looks like it might be amplifying 60Hz/50Hz mains hum?

Comment: Actually, yes, looking at your scope image that's 50Hz. Somewhere, something in your circuit is picking up mains-frequency noise. It could even be related to the oscilloscope you're measuring it with.

Comment: Try aluminium foil over the PD to see what happens. Try earthing the foil. Also try reversing its polarity to see if the problem goes away. What about power rail decoupling - do you have any? Is this amplifier being fed from a sh1tty wall wart?

Comment: What happens if you remove the PD entirely? Is the PD right close to the op-amp or separated?

Comment: Is this a breadboard design or PCB? 

It might be 50Hz noise. When there is no light, the PD goes non-conducting and that helps OA4's negative input drift away from ground. The antenna effect will be worse if you're on a breadboard.

Also, you might want to probe OA4's output and confirm that it is the source. It could be something weird.

Comment: Don't post a question then run. Answer the comments and stick around for at least an hour to service queries.

Comment: You don't "place the photodiode into darkness" by covering it with your hand do you?

Comment: @Andyaka sorry was right at  the end of work and had to leave. I have 100nF caps on the inputs of the photodiodes. I'll try reversing the pd this morning see if it helps. It's being fed through a breadboard but straight from a 5v Bench supply.

Comment: @pscheidler It's on a breadboard at the moment, I have probed OA4 output and it is definitly present there as well. I have pretty long cables from the PD to the op-amp as well at the moment which I know is not ideal but is the only way I could put the circuit together quickly without using Veroboard. Now that Andy has pointed out the power supply Im going to try a 5v regulator on the supply and see if that helps.

Comment: @Felthry Probably from my bench power supply right? thats going straigh onto my 5V rail.

Comment: @JohnD no it's placed in a 3d printed housing.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It is quite far away at the moment but on a similar design I have tried on veroboard it was close and still had similar problem.